# Where in Cluj can I play airsoft?

Tags: romania, entertainment

I'm visiting Cluj, Romania and I would really like to find a place where I can play airsoft nearby the city. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Asking for tips/recommendations is generally against the [help].  Could you be more specific about what you're trying to find?

Answer (score 5):

There's a Facebook page for [Airsoft Cluj](https://www.facebook.com/airsoftcluj), which I imagine would be a great source of expert knowledge in the area, if you were to ask for maybe some people to meet up with.

This is assuming you need a club.  If you're just looking for a field, I'm worried the question may be too broad and may need additional detail.